# Debugging routes in codeigniter?

Tags: php, debugging, codeigniter, logging, codeigniter-routing

I am wondering if there is any simple way of debugging routes in code igniter?

preferably I would like to be able to see in the log along the lines of:

```
Client sent : apps/something
Route found : apps/(:any) --> applications/searchbyname/$1
Redirecting : apps/something --> applications/searchbyname/something
//and just cause we can lets make the searchbyname function not exist
ERROR - 2012-09-16 22:10:05 --> 404 Page Not Found --> applications/searchbyname/something
```

Basically it means we can see when we hit a route and where it is trying to load.

Is there any way to enable something along these lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just wrote a small extension of the Router core system class:

https://github.com/Philo01/CodeIgniter-Route-Debugging

It wil debug just the way you described. ( except for the 404, I still need to add that )

Comment: The 404 should be handled by CI's logging automatically.