# routes.php file not loading when using hmvc in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, hmvc, codeigniter-routing

I have hmvc setup and working fine,

I have a gallery module.

The gallery module breaks down into three controllers and it's structure is as follows:

```
/modules/gallery/
/modules/gallery/config/
/modules/gallery/helpers/
/modules/gallery/controllers/
/modules/gallery/controllers/gallery.php
/modules/gallery/controllers/galleries.php
/modules/gallery/controllers/images.php
/modules/gallery/models/
/modules/gallery/models/galleriesmodel.php
/modules/gallery/models/imagesmodel.php
/modules/gallery/views/dashboard.tpl
/modules/gallery/views/galleries/dashboard.tpl
/modules/gallery/views/images/dashboard.tpl
```

anyway, I have a function inside my `images.php` controller called `list_items`

So I want to map the url
http://example.com/gallery/images/list to
http://example.com/gallery/images/list_items

So I thought, sweet as,
I will just add a `/modules/gallery/config/routes.php` with the route inside it.

But it seems the routes are not being included.

The routes from `/application/config/routes.php` are included and if I put a `die('loaded')` in the module `routes.php` the it does kill the script,

But running

`print_r($this->router)` from one of the controllers does not show up any of the routes from the module `routes.php`.

What's going on here?

Comment: Could you show us the contents of /modules/gallery/config/routes.php?

Comment: `$route['gallery/list'] = 'gallery/images/list_items';`  
`$route['gallery/list/(:any)'] = 'gallery/images/list_items/$1';`

Comment: Have you tried to debug it with the extension I wrote earlier? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446184/debugging-routes-in-codeigniter/12446419

Comment: Yeah, the routes are not being hit

Comment: If you empty the file modules/gallery/config/routes.php. And visit the module http://yoursite.com/gallery you should get the following error: `application/modules/gallery/config/routes.php does not contain a valid route array` This error should indicate that the file gets loaded. If you don't get this error, we know that it does not recognize the routes file.

Comment: And, to confirm, you haven't updated any other core files?

Comment: Because I am using hmvc there are the hmvc core overrides e.g. MY_router.php but not on top of that

Comment: Why don't you put a routing system in the controller itself instead ?

Comment: Because I have several controllers per module. And I don't want to have to remap every function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know,

HMVC only looks for requested controllers inside each module, with different hierarchy models, but route overrides using routes.php within modules are never read.

Look into `MX_Router::locate` it never looks for `routes.php` inside any module.

Also it does not override `CI_Router::_set_routing` which looks for `routes.php` in config folder.

You will have to override `CI_Router::_set_routing` and read `config/router.php` in every available module for your module route overrides to work.

Answer (score 0):

Broncha shows the way, I show you the code. **I use this SOLUTION:**

You have to edit `_set_routing()` in `system/core/Router.php` or extend this method (better) within MY_Router class (`third_party/Router.php`).

Now it should always load `module/config/routes.php`... *(it's around line 140)*

```
// Load the routes.php file.
        if (defined('ENVIRONMENT') AND is_file(APPPATH.'config/'.ENVIRONMENT.'/routes.php'))
        {
            include(APPPATH.'config/'.ENVIRONMENT.'/routes.php');
        }
        elseif (is_file(APPPATH.'config/routes.php'))
        {
            include(APPPATH.'config/routes.php');
        }

        // Include routes every modules
        $modules_locations = config_item('modules_locations') ? config_item('modules_locations') : FALSE;
        if(!$modules_locations)
        {
            $modules_locations = APPPATH . 'modules/';
            if(is_dir($modules_locations))
            {
                $modules_locations = array($modules_locations => '../modules/');
            }
            else
            {
                show_error('Modules directory not found');
            }
        }
        foreach ($modules_locations as $key => $value)
        {
            if ($handle = opendir($key))
            {
                while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle)))
                {
                    if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..")
                    {
                        if(is_dir($key.$entry))
                        {
                            $rfile = Modules::find('routes'.EXT, $entry, 'config/');
                            if($rfile[0])
                            {
                                include($rfile[0].$rfile[1]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                closedir($handle);
            }
        } 

        $this->routes = ( ! isset($route) OR ! is_array($route)) ? array() : $route;
        unset($route);
```

I hope it will help...