# CodeIgniter show accessed route/translated controller on 404 page

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

Now, when CodeIgniter does not find a controller for a route or a route for the uri, it shows a generic 404 page. How can I show the accessed route or controller or something useful that would allow me to debug why it's showed a 404?

Code:

```
switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'multiplelines.domain.ro': 
             $route['default_controller'] = "subdomain"; break;
    default: $route['default_controller'] = "welcome"; break;
}


$route['scaffolding_trigger'] = "";
$route['404_override'] = '';
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "www.domain.ro" 
   || $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "domain.ro")
{
  // URI like '/en/about' -> use controller 'about'
  $route['^(romana|english|magyar)/(.+)$'] = "$2";

  // '/en', '/de', '/fr' and '/nl' URIs -> use default controller
  $route['^(romana|english|magyar)$'] = $route['default_controller'];
}
else
{

}
```

Desired effect:
When on www or empty subdomain routing will occur like this:
/language/test will go to test controller

When on another subdomain (I just listed one case) will be routing to the subdomain controller as I just want to use one controller for those.

Note: Now when on www or empty subdomain there is code to choose the language automatically for /test route for test controller (without language directory in uri).

Comment: Copy paste your router code which dont works..

Comment: Added code as requested. Thanks

Comment: so you want CI to display to you something it can't find in the first place? :)  ("How can I show the accessed route or controller")

Comment: To be more specific, I want some debug information, what route he tried to access, what controller tried to access and didn't found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When CI dont find correct Route for a page it knows that there isn't such page so it is giving 404 NOT EXISTING..

If user try to open /sgasgasggsasga page at your site it gets 404 for the same reason..

You have to find by yourself why its showing 404...

Look at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Enable [error logging](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html) on your application.

Then, once you look up the errors, you will see the URI that was requested that generated the 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Will fill in answer properly when on computer, but have a look at [Debugging routes in codeigniter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446184/debugging-routes-in-codeigniter) it has route logging

Answer (score 0):

> How can I show the accessed route or controller or something useful that would allow me to debug why it's showed a 404?

You could echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] in the 404 view to determine where the user was trying to go.